# Como criar guias dentro de uma janela?

Tags: c#, winforms

Preciso criar um programa que exiba os forms que eu vou chamando pelo MenuStrip, dentro do form principal, como se fossem parte dele, e que dê para deixar mais de um aberto. Acredito que pela imagem que eu fiz fica mais fácil de entender o que eu quero.

Então, quais componentes eu tenho que usar e como eu faço isso?

[image: rascunho]

Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Voce pode usar componente **panel** para colocar um form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa usar o componente **`TabControl`**. Ele é "controlador" das tabs, o *container* delas.

As tabs propriamente ditas são o controle **`TabPage`**.

Comment: Mas é possível jogar um form pronto dentro de uma TabPage ou eu vou ter meio que recriar o form dentro de uma TapPage?